Mapping Jack's Chicken

Clues:
Map of world with numbers 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, and 9 strategically placed.
Portrait of man with numbers 1x2, 2, 3, 5, and 5 strategically placed in hair.
Instructions: Name That Film
_ _ _ _ E _ _ _ _ _
The original had an error! Click below to see original.

  The 10 in the hair has been changed to a 3, and location updated.


Are you sure about this? _ _ _ _ E _ _ _ _ _. Gemini could not find any name of film with that name.:)

How about Mastermind ?

Do the pointers on the map point to specific place precisely or do they just give an idea of where the hint belongs?

The film is

ERASERHEAD!!


The numbers on the left

Correlate to the letters of the words:

Pacific
cAnada
iNdian ocean
arGentina
australiA
grEenland
chinA

So taking these letters we get the word PANGAEA

And indeed

The outline of the hair is actually the outline of Pangaea rotated to look like hair:



So

Using the same method we get:

auStralia
mExico
unitEd states
chinA
Russia x2

Giving the letters SEEARR

And

These letters are an anagram of ‘ERASER’

Finally

This word is on the persons head, or as a rebus 'ERASER HEAD'

Giving the film as ERASERHEAD!!

(Thanks @Stiv and @Bart-JanvanRossum for finding the film!)

And the title and picture

Is a reference to the lead actor Jack Nance, and his chicken dinner in the film!

The person in the puzzle is the same as the films poster:




I've got to this exact point too. I also wondered if your RR might also be rot13(FF - F(vorevn)) but nothing sticking yet... rot13(OENIRURNEG svgf vs lbh pna trg gur O, I, U naq G sebz fbzrjurer!)

@Stiv think we're definitely missing something, way too many vowels at the moment!

I think for the first part the 2 is not India but rather the Indian ocean but that doesn't change anything.

@quarague ah yep, wrote it wrong in the answer good catch

Error in original puzzle has been fixed. You're there!

Aha, with the fix I'm pretty sure this is rot13(RENFREURNQ)!

@Stiv thanks for finding it! Was still struggling after the fix :P

And the image is of the actor, I guess.

Are you sure about the anagram? It doesn't seem correct. Probably where you use HAIR you should use HEAD

@Bart-JanvanRossum oh wait, good point there’s obviously no ‘I’ :P Will fix now
